# Deleting CloudFormation VPC stack without disassociating the Elastic IP causes delete to fail

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I've got a CloudFormation stack (anonymised version at https://gist.github.com/palfrey/7021931) that creates correctly, but attempting to delete it fails trying to delete the VPCGatewayAttachment, because it complains about the VPC having mapped public addresses. If however, I disassociate the Elastic IP from the Instance which is inside the VPC first, it works fine.

Things of note from the stack JSON:

- The elastic IP and the VPCGatewayAttachment are created and associated as part of the stack creation. I don't make any changes between creation and deletion.
- I'm using the AWS Powershell helpers to create and destroy, specifically New-CFNStack and Remove-CFNStack, but manually deleting the stack from the AWS console has the same results.
- The delete sequences from the AWS console indicates it's trying to delete the VPCGatewayAttachment before the Elastic IP, but if I disassociate it does things in the right order.

I can work around this by disassociating the Elastic IP myself beforehand, but I'm confused as to why it doesn't just do things in the correct order, given that CloudFormation seems to know about other dependencies in the delete sequence.

Answer (score 2):

The current (as of 4/2016) solution is to add a [`DependsOn`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html) attribute in your [`AWS::EC2::EIP`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-eip.html) resource pointing to the [`AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-vpc-gateway-attachment.html) resource.

See the AWS CloudFormation documentation for [When a DependsOn attribute is required](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html#gatewayattachment):

> Some resources in a VPC require a gateway (either an Internet or VPN gateway). If your AWS CloudFormation template defines a VPC, a gateway, and a gateway attachment, any resources that require the gateway are dependent on the gateway attachment. For example, an Amazon EC2 instance with a public IP address is dependent on the VPC-gateway attachment if the VPC and InternetGateway resources are also declared in the same template.
>
> Currently, the following resources depend on a VPC-gateway attachment when they have an associated public IP address and are in a VPC:
>
> - Auto Scaling groups
> - **Amazon EC2 instances**
> - Elastic Load Balancing load balancers
> - **Elastic IP addresses**
> - Amazon RDS database instances
> - **Amazon VPC routes that include the Internet gateway**

In your example you would need to add `"DependsOn": "AttachGateway"` to the `WebServer`, `WebServerEIP`, and `Route` resources (bolded in the above quote), e.g.,

```
"WebServerEIP": {
        "Type" : "AWS::EC2::EIP",
        "DependsOn" : "AttachGateway",
        [...]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the deallocation order of the elastic IP address and was introduced when CloudFormation went from single to parallel processing.

AWS are aware of it, and hopefully they can get it on the roadmap to get it fixed soon. In the meantime, the somewhat unacceptable workaround is to run the remove-cfn stack again.

(We actually have a helper which runs the remove, and keeps calling delete until it's finally decided to be deleted)